# Vedic tradition of Samudrika Shastra

Tags: vedas, scripture

Samudrika Shastra is a part of the Vedic tradition.Many people in the vedic ages, utilized this knowledge for studying the human face, body features,body aura etc. This tradition assumes that every natural or acquired bodily mark, encodes its owner's psychology and destiny. Elevation, depression, elongation, diminution, and other marks become relevant. There are five main types of human elements in terms of the Samudrika: Agni(Fire), Vayu(Air), Jal(Water), Akash(Sky,Space) and Prithvi(Earth).

Which are the authentic texts, for understanding Samudrika Shastra?

Comment: It seems " Samudrika Shastra" is part of Astrology (joytish shastra). According to some sited it  is written by  Kartikeya and some says by Brahma.
The only shloka i have found is "पूर्णचंद्रमुखी या च बालसूर्य-समप्रभा।
विशालनेत्रा विम्बोष्ठी सा कन्या लभते सुखम् ।1।
या च कांचनवर्णाभ रक्तपुष्परोरुहा।
सहस्त्राणां तु नारीणां भवेत् सापि पतिव्रता ।2। "  Unfortunately not much aurhetic  scriptures found ,hence the comment.

Comment: Yes , the site provides some info. On face reading. Thanks for the link:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Samudrika Shastra is described in [Garuda Purana, Chapter 58-66](https://archive.org/details/garudapuranam00duttgoog) translated by Manmatha Nath Dutt.

Samudrika is also described in [Bhavishya Purana, Vol 1, chapter 5](http://m.exoticindia.com/m/book/details/book/bhavishya-purana-volume-i-IDJ643/).

Answer (score 3):

There are many classics on Samudrika Sastra or Palmistry. Here I am mentioning few important ones. In future, I hope to add more to this list.

1. Hasta Sanjivani or Hasta Sanjivan - This is a very important book, whose shlokas are usually quoted frequently in Indian Palmistry books.
   https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/palmistry-mzh439/
2. Vivek Vilas
   https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/vivek-vilas-nze375/
3. Hasta Vimbakara - I could not find any online link to this book yet. However, shlokas from this book are also quoted in many chapters.

Comment: How much these are practical in real life? To what extent these are helpful? Do you have any experience of these?

Comment: @User29449 I have not read any Indian classics on Hastarekha. However, palmistry in general, works. I know that from my personal experience and reading modern western classics on Palmistry.

Comment: How accurate is Palmistry in a normal context? Is it just a one-time thing (as the lines in the palm don't change), or it needs to be checked from time to time? Also is it good to invest time learning basics of those?

Comment: @User29449 Lines in palm do change!!! take a photograph of your palm. and check after a few years. Minor lines that you do not pay attention, changes based on your decisions. For example, a love line can get erased if you don't accept the girl!

Comment: Ah, this I wasn't aware of! Are there very short resources to get started? And what does an ideal palm line should look like for a person seeking liberation?

Comment: @User29449 I am not an expert on palmistry. I only know a little bit. You can read Saint Germain's or Cheiro's book of palmistry. Cheiro is a world-famous palmist. He is a westerner. However, he learned palmistry from India.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll look into it! :)